# Snowflake Python Connector - Breaks When Run By Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: python, authentication, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, windows-task-scheduler

My python script connects to Snowflake when run from the command line or from an IPython Notebook. When I manually run the script, it opens up a browser window and automatically signs me in using AzureAD. However, the same exact script stalls when it's triggered by Windows Task Scheduler?

Any ideas why this script is unable to open a browser and authenticate with Snowflake when it's triggered by Windows Task Scheduler?

```
import snowflake.connector

cnx = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user = 'first.last@myCompany.com',
    authenticator = 'externalbrowser',
    account = 'myCompanyName',
    warehouse = 'myWarehouse',
    database = 'myDatabase',
    schema = 'mySchema',
    role = 'myRole'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways,

1. creating .bat file which will open python in command prompt.
2. directly using python.exe to run file.

reference:
for .bat file: https://datatofish.com/python-script-windows-scheduler/

for python.exe: https://www.jcchouinard.com/python-automation-using-task-scheduler/

I use both methods on regular basis and it works perfect.

**Note:** please check all the packages are installed in instance which is running your file.